# Evitar que llegue spam del formulario

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, recaptcha

Tengo un formulario que se creo en ZOHO CRM y posteriormente se coloco en el código de un sitio web junto con un recapcha V2. El problema que estoy presentando con el formulario es que esta llegando demasiado spam (aproximadamente 150 correos por día) y quiero saber el porque si se supone que ya trae un recapcha.

Anexo código del sito web.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-jp">

    <title><?=$title?> | Abacom</title>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Cuerpo -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        </style>
            <!-- Contact Form Section Start -->
            <div class="contact-form-area white-bg section-padding" style="padding-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 5%;">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- formulario CRM -->
                    <div id="crmWebToEntityForm">
                            <form id="form_contactanos" action='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm' name=WebToLeads54017000024509001 method='POST' onSubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatory54017000024509001()' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
                                
                            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm" id="form_contactanos" method="POST" name="WebToLeads54017000024509001" onsubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatory54017000024509001()'>
                            <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
                            <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xnQsjsdp' value='b8c6293891e2878f125a78c114c45d1133cd8ab0fd31519fb0e76a930012c594'/>
                            <input type='hidden' name='zc_gad' id='zc_gad' value=''/>
                            <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xmIwtLD' value='8a7419917526917cd8f7bdba23036d4e935b1802ac851f769d3da91bf2a3431e'/>
                            <input type='text' style='display:none;'  name='actionType' value='TGVhZHM='/>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-5 text-center">
                                        <div class="heading mb-85">
                            <input type="hidden" id="pagina_landing" name="pagina_landing" value="Cotízame" />
                                            <h5 style="color: #2581c4;">
                                                Siempre estamos listos
                                            </h5>
                                            <h3>
                                                Platícanos de tu Proyecto
                                            </h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="Company" name="Company" placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa" type="text" required/>
                                            <!-- </input> -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Tu Nombre" type="text" required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1" style="display: none">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="Last Name" name="Last Name" placeholder="Tu Apellido" type="text" value="nuevo prospecto" required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="Phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Teléfono" type="text" required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail" type="email" required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="LEADCF20" name="LEADCF20" placeholder="¿Dónde se encuentra tu empresa?" type="text" required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>¿Cuál es el giro de tu empresa?</label>
                                            <select  class="custom-select col-12" id="Industry" name="Industry">
                                                <option value="">
                                                    ---Seleccione---
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="ASP">
                                                    ASP
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Comercio Electrónico">
                                                    Comercio Electrónico
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Comercio Exterior">
                                                    Comercio Exterior
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Corporativo/Grande">
                                                    Corporativo/Grande
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Educacion/Capacitacion">
                                                    Educacion/Capacitacion
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Embajadas y Consulados">
                                                    Embajadas y Consulados
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Empresas de Servicios">
                                                    Empresas de Servicios
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Gobierno/Militar">
                                                    Gobierno/Militar
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria Aeronáutica">
                                                    Industria Aeronáutica
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria Automotriz">
                                                    Industria Automotriz
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria de Alimentos">
                                                    Industria de Alimentos
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria de la Construcción">
                                                    Industria de la Construcción
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria de las Telecomunicaciones">
                                                    Industria de las Telecomunicaciones
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria Energética">
                                                    Industria Energética
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria Hotelera">
                                                    Industria Hotelera
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria Inmobiliaria">
                                                    Industria Inmobiliaria
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria Manufactura">
                                                    Industria Manufactura
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria Maquiladora">
                                                    Industria Maquiladora
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Industria Metalmecanica">
                                                    Industria Metalmecanica
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Proyectos de Infraestructura">
                                                    Proyectos de Infraestructura
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PyME/Mediana Empresa">
                                                    PyME/Mediana Empresa
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Salud">
                                                    Salud
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Sector Financiero y Bancos">
                                                    Sector Financiero y Bancos
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Servicios Financieros, inmobiliarios y de Alquiler">
                                                    Servicios Financieros, inmobiliarios y de Alquiler
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Servicios Tecnicos Profesionales, Personales y Soc">
                                                    Servicios Tecnicos Profesionales, Personales y Soc
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="SoHo/Micro Empresa">
                                                    SoHo/Micro Empresa
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Transportes y Comunicaciones">
                                                    Transportes y Comunicaciones
                                                </option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>¿Qué servicio o producto necesitas?</label>
                                            <select  class="custom-select col-12" id="LEADCF27" name="LEADCF27">
                                                <option value="">
                                                    ---Seleccione---
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Cableado estructurado">
                                                    Cableado estructurado
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Conectividad (Internet y Acceso)">
                                                    Conectividad (Internet y Acceso)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Conmutador y accesorios">
                                                    Conmutador y accesorios
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Consultoría (Analisis, Diseño, Evaluación)">
                                                    Consultoría (Analisis, Diseño, Evaluación)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Equipo de Computo">
                                                    Equipo de Computo
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Equipo de red">
                                                    Equipo de red
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Proyecto de Solución Integral">
                                                    Proyecto de Solución Integral
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Solución Integrada">
                                                    Solución Integrada
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Soporte Tecnico">
                                                    Soporte Tecnico
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="Telefonía IP">
                                                    Telefonía IP
                                                </option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="LEADCF30" name="LEADCF30" placeholder="Cuéntanos más de tu proyecto:" required>
                                            </textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf1_mkgAAAAAN2h946VguCZvoKIkjaBfrnoiAkI"></div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-10 offset-sm-0 offset-1 text-center">
                                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                                                <a onclick="form_contactanos(event);" class="btn btn-outline-inverse btn-rounded btn-md btn-arrow m-t-20" type="submit">
                                                    <span>
                                                        Enviar
                                                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right">
                                                        </i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.ROW -->
                                <script>
                                    var mndFileds=new Array('Company','First Name','Last Name','Phone','Email','LEADCF27');
                                    var fldLangVal=new Array('Company','First Name','Last Name','Phone','Email','Tipo de Negocio');
                                    var name='';
                                    var email='';

                                      function checkMandatory54017000024509001() {
                                        for(i=0;i<mndFileds.length;i++) {
                                          var fieldObj=document.forms['WebToLeads54017000024509001'][mndFileds[i]];
                                          if(fieldObj) {
                                            if (((fieldObj.value).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')).length==0) {
                                             if(fieldObj.type =='file')
                                                {
                                                 alert('Please select a file to upload.');
                                                 fieldObj.focus();
                                                 return false;
                                                }
                                            alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be empty.');
                                              fieldObj.focus();
                                              return false;
                                            }  else if(fieldObj.nodeName=='SELECT') {
                                             if(fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value=='-None-') {
                                                alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be none.');
                                                fieldObj.focus();
                                                return false;
                                               }
                                            } else if(fieldObj.type =='checkbox'){
                                             if(fieldObj.checked == false){
                                                alert('Please accept  '+fldLangVal[i]);
                                                fieldObj.focus();
                                                return false;
                                               }
                                             }
                                             try {
                                                 if(fieldObj.name == 'Last Name') {
                                                name = fieldObj.value;
                                                }
                                            } catch (e) {}
                                            }
                                        }
                                         }
                                </script>
                        </input>
                            </form>
                        <!-- </meta> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Contact Form Section End -->
            <!-- Contact Info Section Start -->
            <!-- Services Section -->
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="services">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="contact-info-area white-bg section-pt total spacer bg-light team4">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row row-eq-height no-gutter">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 card-shadow add-image-2" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-duration="1200">
                                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/contactanos/contactanos.jpg" width="100%">
                                    </img>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 add-image-2" style="background-color: #fff;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                                            <div class="info-box">
                                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x">
                                                </i>
                                                <h6>
                                                    HORARIO
                                                </h6>
                                                <p style="font-size: 16px;">
                                                    Lun a Vie – 9:00 AM a 6:00 PM
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 text-center">
                                            <div class="info-box">
                                                <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x">
                                                </i>
                                                <h6>
                                                    TELEFONO
                                                </h6>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a href="tel:(442)1611010" style="color: #333333!important; font-size: 16px;">
                                                        (442) 161 1010
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                                            <div class="info-box">
                                                <i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-2x">
                                                </i>
                                                <h6>
                                                    DIRECCIÓN
                                                </h6>
                                                <p style="font-size: 16px">
                                                    Calle Guanajuato #240
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Col. Roma Delegación Cuauhtémoc CP.06700 Cuidad de México
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./Cuerpo -->
     <script>
        function form_contactanos(e) {

            var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

            e.preventDefault();
            if(response.length == 0){
              alert("Captcha no verificado");
            } else {
                var compania = document.getElementById('Company').value;
                var nombre = document.getElementById('Name').value;
                var apellido = document.getElementById('Last Name').value;
                var telefono = document.getElementById('Phone').value;
                var email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
                var ubicacion = document.getElementById('LEADCF20').value;
                var giro = document.getElementById('Industry').value;
                var prodser = document.getElementById('LEADCF27').value;
                var textarea = document.getElementById('LEADCF30').value;

                if (compania !== "") {
                    if (nombre !== "") {
                            if (telefono !== "" && (/^\d{10}$/.test(telefono))) {
                                if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(email)) {
                                    if (ubicacion !== "") {
                                        if (giro !== "") {
                                            if (prodser !== "") {
                                                if (textarea !== "") {
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        url: "<?php echo base_url('Abacom/ajax_send_form'); ?>",
                                                        data: $("#form_contactanos").serialize(),
                                                        success: function(data) {
                                                            swal({
                                                                title: "Buen trabajo!",
                                                                text: "Se envi¨® correctamente!",
                                                                icon: "success",
                                                                button: true,
                                                                dangerMode: false,
                                                            })
                                                            .then((willDelete) => {
                                                                if (willDelete) {
                                                                    $("#form_contactanos").submit();
                                                                    // $("#form_contactanos").trigger('reset');
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                        },
                                                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                            alert('algo salio mal');
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                } else {
                                                    alert('El campo esta vac¨ªo.');
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                alert('Selecciona una opci¨®n.');
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            alert('Selecciona una opci¨®n.');
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        alert('El campo esta vac¨ªo.');
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    alert('El E-mail es incorrecto');
                                }
                            } else {
                                alert('El numero es de 10 d¨ªgitos.');
                            }
                    } else {
                        alert('El campo esta vac¨ªo.');
                    }
                } else {
                  alert('El campo esta vac¨ªo.');
                }
            }
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
var $zoho=$zoho || {};$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {widgetcode:"323a03d4fc62756882e34a2c27bb028edaade236ab5390ed36ccb617947e9ec8", values:{},ready:function(){}};var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.id="zsiqscript";s.defer=true;s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);d.write("<div id='zsiqwidget'></div>");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $zoho=$zoho || {};$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {widgetcode:"323a03d4fc62756882e34a2c27bb028edaade236ab5390ed36ccb617947e9ec8", values:{},ready:function(){}};var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.id="zsiqscript";s.defer=true;s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);d.write("<div id='zsiqwidget'></div>");
</script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
    <!-- ./Archivos JS -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta ha sido marcada automáticamente por el sistema por ser demasiado extensa. Debes tratar de reducir el alcance de la pregunta o el código incluido en la misma. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Qué pasa si un programa carga el formulario sin JS? Tus validaciones evitan el spam?

Answer (score 0):

El spam es casi imposible de prevenir al 100%, pero los números que indicas son definitivamente muy altos. Una posibilidad es que estás haciendo la comprobación y validación en JavaScript y eso hace que sea muy fácil saltársela.

En el código de tu página tienes esta función que procesa el formulario y lo manda:

```
  function form_contactanos(e) {

    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    e.preventDefault();
    if(response.length == 0){
      alert("Captcha no verificado");
    } else {
        var compania = document.getElementById('Company').value;
        var nombre = document.getElementById('Name').value;
        var apellido = document.getElementById('Last Name').value;
        var telefono = document.getElementById('Phone').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
        var ubicacion = document.getElementById('LEADCF20').value;
        var giro = document.getElementById('Industry').value;
        var prodser = document.getElementById('LEADCF27').value;
        var textarea = document.getElementById('LEADCF30').value;
```

Bastaría cambiar la siguiente línea:

```
  var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
```

por algo como:

```
  var response = "Valido!";
```

Para saltarse toda la validación sin problemas.

No sé cómo funciona grecaptcha, pero mirando la [documentación de Google](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3), parece que no se están haciendo bien las validaciones.

Debes seguir los pasos que se indican en el [tutorial de la versión 3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#automatically_bind_the_challenge_to_a_button):

1. Cargar la API JavaScript (esto lo haces)

   ```
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
   ```
2. Añadir una función callback para manejar el token

   ```
   <script>
     function onSubmit(token) {
       document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
     }
   </script>
   ```
3. Añadir los atributos necesarios al botón de enviar (tú tienes un enlace de enviar que es otro problema aparte):

   ```
   <button class="g-recaptcha" 
           data-sitekey="reCAPTCHA_site_key" 
           data-callback='onSubmit' 
           data-action='submit'>Submit</button>
   ```